# why is "->" included in this example

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand gradual typing and I came across the example below

```
def sum(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    return num1 + num2

print(sum(2, 3))
print(sum(1, 'Geeks'))
```

what does the "->" do and why is it there?

Comment: It indicates that `int` is the return type of the function.